# Azure App Service Certificates Error on importing into key vault

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-keyvault, azure-appservice

I have purchased an Azure app service certificate for an "A" record. After that, I am trying to import the certificate into the key vault, but I am getting error code 500 as shown on the attached screen.

Step 1 - in Azure
**Import certificate into Key Vault for secure administration.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved after a couple of hours.